# Google Maps API v3 Multiple Markers with Info Windows & pins

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I know similar questions has been asked before, however I can't find one that talks about *Multiple Markers with Info Windows and different pins*. I have succeeded in creating multiple markers with info windows, but I want those *markers* to have *different pins according to their type,* which will be *store in an array* along with the position etc. Here is my code

```
  var iconBase = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/";
  var icons = {
    test1: {
      icon: iconBase + "mm_20_purple.png"
    },
    test2: {
      icon: iconBase + "mm_20_yellow.png"
    },
    test3: {
      icon: iconBase + "mm_20_green.png"
    }
  };      

  function LoadMap() {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var data = markers[i];
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title,

        // Icon markers called here!
        icon: icons[markers.type].icon
        // =========================

      });
   }
```

You can find the full working version of the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/vLjz4pxz/). At the moment the only thing that doesn't work is the pins which aren't being rendered.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change

`icon: icons[markers.type].icon`

To:

`icon: icons[data.type].icon` or `icon: icons[markers[i].type].icon` (both work in your case)

That's because `markers.type` does not exist. But you have declared `var data = markers[i];` so the actual marker inside the loop is saved on `data` variable.

Comment: @AaronMatthews answer was from MTK, not from me ;)

Comment: oh I see, I should read more carefully next time, thank you @MTK!